# Can pumps pull 10 meters elevation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, flow

I'm in a voluntary fire fighting group. Fire fighting pumping equipment states in documentation that they can pump from open source of water 10 meters below the pump.

My understanding:

- This can not be a self-evacuating pump. The system must be completely prefilled with water. Otherwise the pump would need to create the theoretically perfect vacuum to even be considered.
- Even the smallest air pocket in the pump house, connectors or valve could be problematic since the pocket will expand at lower pressure.
- With a completely evacuated pump, you will be able to "pull" on the water up to 10 meter water column inside a tube, but above that is not possible because the external pressure of 1 bar will not push it further up.
- So, if we imagine a 20 meter vertical syringe like construct where the tip is submerged and where the piston starts at water level, the piston can pull upwards to about 10 meters, where the water will not go higher and the space that forms between the piston and the top of the water column will be vacuum (-like).
- But, there are more things that happens when the pressure drops. Water that has been in an open source will contain gas molecules, which will form bubbles when the pressure drops (like a carbonated soda). I assume at some point close to the 10 meter mark, these bubbles will interfere with the above mentioned vacuum. But the practical implication of this, both in terms of the water column height and workings of a pump, is not obvious to me.
- In addition, by the intake the pressure will be so low that we may have to consider that the low pressure also lowers the boiling temperature of water. I know that at 600-700 pascals, water can no longer exist as liquid, but this is at 0.007 bar where we probably are practically at 10 meters, so I don't know if the moving boiling point or the hard limit at 700 pascals would be of practical importance.
- Inertia could be factor. That a pump can sustain a flow at a higher elevation than it can start a flow. But I don't see how it would be practically useful since you would need to move the pump while in operation and with connected water filled intake and outlet equipment/tubes/hoses.

So, would you call BS if a fire fighting pump documentation stated that it could pull water from an open body of water 10 meters below it?

Comment: Almost certainly the manufacturer has tested the pump beyond 10 meters, but uses 10m as a cut-off to ensure more safe usage (i.e., less failures from abuse of going to its actual failure point), so probably not at all BS. Either way, though, I don't think this is really a physics question but more of an engineering one.

Comment: There is absolutely no theoretical way that anything can suck above 10 meters. Even if it could create theoretical perfect vacuum, the water column pushed by the atmosphere could never exceed 10 meters. The question was if the other factors, such as inertia, change in boiling point and bubbles forming due to drop in pressure.
Clearly a physics question. 
Clearly NOT an engineering question since the question allows for a theoretical perfect pump.

Comment: Your question is asking if it's BS for a manufacturer to have made something to some specifications. That's not physics, that's engineering. A simple phone call to the MFR would have solved your problem.

Comment: I am asking if it the physics is plausible. Even given an ideal pump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless it is a [submersible pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersible_pump), then a 10 metre lift does seem optimistic. As you note, suction pumps are limited by atmospheric pressure which typically corresponds to about a [10.3 metre column of water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_pressure#Measurement_based_on_the_depth_of_water) at sea level, and this is likely what the manufacturer is referring to.  This theoretical maximum will be reduced at altitude, such as when [fighting mountain wildfires](https://www.nwcg.gov/course/ffm/squirt-water/35-drafting-guidelines).

It is [often stated](https://www.practicalcottager.com/water2.php) that the practical lift limit is 7-8 metres, for [reasons](https://www.mecaflux.com/en/hauteur_aspiration.htm) similar to those you mention. A [recent MSc thesis](https://digitalcommons.usf.edu/etd/7056/) however, reports that the practical lift limit of manually operated pumps may actually be greater than 9 metres for large bore (2 inch) pipes. One can find [other references](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316090854_Performance_evaluation_of_a_centrifugal_pump_under_different_suction_lifts) to 9 m lifts.  So it may not be impossible that under ideal conditions your pump can achieve a lift of 9.5 m (for example), which the manufacturer has rounded up to 10 m.  Of course, even if the pump can lift that height, that does not mean the flow rate would be sufficient to fight a fire.

As others have commented, it would probably be best to ask the manufacturer for clarification.

Comment: Thank you. The question was closed due to "apparently being an engineering question", which is odd since the question allows for a theoretically perfect pump and asks how other physics factor in. 
I mark as accepted since the 10.3meter, 9 meters and 9.5 meters helped me along.
Yes, I believe that the reason is because they are asking themselves how close to the 10m mark they "dare" to put the specs. And nobody wants to appear to be underperforming with respect to competitors.
And, yes, if the inlet is below 10 meters (which includes a submersible pump) then clearly it can PUSH much more.